# Change select box style

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change select box style by using css and jquery  is it possible?

Comment: Could you be a little more explicit about what you want to change?  You want to change from single- to multiple-select or just change one of the CSS properties?

Answer (score 2):

u can use one of this plugin

http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements

Answer (score 1):

Not cross browser using the default select element.

The filament group have a select menu [plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) that will enhance a select tag (basically replace it with other elements for js users giving a better experience)

Answer (score 0):

There is the .css() jQuery function, but I would shy away from changing styles in this way. Keeping the CSS in one place is definaley a plus.

You could declare another class in your CSS stylesheet, and use the jQuery class functions - `.addClass() .removeClass() .toggleClass()` functions to change the style on the element that way.

For example:

```
$("#MySelect").removeClass("OldClass").addClass("NewClass");
```

Or, if you ever wanted to toggle between:

```
$("#MySelect").toggleClass("OldClass").toggleClass("NewClass");
```

Not tested, but should be ok or nearly ok!

Comment: At a guess, because you misunderstood the use of the word 'how' here.  The author was certainly asking if there are css rules that control the look of a select box, not if there's a jquery function that lets you set css rules.

Answer (score 0):

**SelectBoxIt** is a plugin I created that allows you to style and animate a select box.

http://www.selectboxit.com